# strlen() not working with string variable

Tags: c++, c++11, strlen

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string b="hello";

    cout<<b;

    int c = strlen(b);

    cout << "Hello world!" <<c<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this I get the error below

```
||=== Build: Debug in strlen (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Waters\Desktop\hellow world\strlen\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Waters\Desktop\hellow world\strlen\main.cpp|14|error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: try `strlen(b.c_str())`

Comment: this worked but I would like to know how did it work

Comment: even better: try `c = b.length()`

Comment: @WatersSharma: because `strlen` takes a `char *` argument, not an `std::string`, which is totally meaningless to it. `std::string::c_str()` is a function returning a C string (`const char *`).

Comment: @WatersSharma: if you bothered to read the error message, it says right there: `cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t strlen(const char*)'`

Comment: Whatever source you're learning from, throw it out and get a decent book.

Comment: @dgsomerton thank you

Comment: @molbdnilo which book do you suggest

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/620382

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) is a function from C and works with C strings (`char *`).

For proper C++ `std::string`s use the [`.length()` or `.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member functions.

In fact most standard headers that start with 'c' include functions that C++ inherited from C. In your case you most likely don't have any reason to use `<cstring>` if you're already working with C++ strings.

Answer (score 0):

your case will work if you just changed

```
string b="hello";
```

to

```
char* b = "hello";
```

note that C strings always (should) have null character '\0' that determines that end of the string.
It's explained briefly for example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)

Comment: You surely meant, C strings must be terminated by `'\0'` not by `'\n'`.

Comment: @cwschmidt aha, you are damn right :D I should probably get some sleep

Comment: also `const char *b` instead of `char *b`.

Comment: @cwschmidt well, in the example string isn't const

Comment: @Peregrin What do you refer to? It's irrelevant if it's `const` or not, C strings have to be terminated by `'\0'`